# Google Big Query Wildcard Data sets

Tags: mysql, database, google-bigquery, wildcard

I have 45 CSV files stores in google cloud storage in the same folder, when wild carding these into a data set table I am finding that some of the rows are missing once I connect the data to tableau. If I just select one of the files all the data will appear. all the files are called "PMPRO_PIVOT_ASDKE" the last 5 digits will change for each file. I have tried wildcarding with "PMPRO_PIVOT*" and it will take data from each file but some of the data is missing from each file.

Any ideas would be great as I've been trying to solve this all day.

Comment: are you using permanent external table or temporary tables. can you share how you bq mk the table and the whole query.

Comment: Hi Nathan, you'll have to forgive me im very new to google biq query and SQL in general, I created the table using storage buckets in google cloud storage and then using the created table function in BigQuery. "accountdash/pm pivots 17/*" is my link to the storage which picks up every file but misses some of the data within the file. Looking at the query history I can't see anything wrong with the way its querying the data, as when I chose to select just one of the files without the wildcard it will work fine. The SQL query is not limiting the data to return a limited numbers of rows.

Comment: provide the query you use in the question. I understand that you are Querying Cloud Storage data using permanent external tables, if not please be more explicit on what you are doing. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#permanent-tables